# Java regex beginning and ending metadata characters error

Tags: java, regex

```
String pat = "^(?!US\\b)(\\w{2})(.*)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("US 123");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Why can't I do this in Java? What do I use to match a beginning and ending metacharacter in a Java RegExp then?

Comment: What do you mean by cannot use this in Java?

Comment: What happens when you try to use it? Do you get an exception, or no matches, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. It appears you are attempting to match the letters `US` followed by a boundary character. In that case you can use:

```
String pat = "(\\w{2}\\b)(.*)";
```

The start & end end of line anchors are unnecessary in this case as you're using `Matcher#find`

Comment: `The start & end end of line anchors are unnecessary as you're using Matcher#find` I think you're confusing `find` with `matches`.

Comment: Whenever you want to match on the complete input instead of its subsequence.

Comment: I don't think the line I've pointed out conveys the same. It's misleading then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting to find a match here (group(1) = 123) but the negative look-ahead that you're doing `^(?!US\\b)` won't pass since the string starts with `US`. This also proves that start `^` and end `$` of input meta characters work fine for regex in Java.